# How to generate pdf or words file that using data input by the user at the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, web

I cant figure out how to make the pdf file get the data input by the user from the website  Icreated. The data is successfully retrieve by the database and now I dont know how to make the data from the database to be placed into the pdf file or words.

This is the coding I tried.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Generate CV" onclick="generatePDF()">
</center>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-invoice-template@1.4.0/dist/index.js"></script>
<script src="lectureredit.js"></script>
```

and this is the Javascript code:

```
function generatePDF(){
    var Lecturername = document.getElementById('nameField').value;
    
    props.business.name = Lecturername;  
    var pdfObject = jsPDFInvoiceTemplate.default(props);
    console.log("CV generated : ",pdfObject);
}
        
var props = {
    outputType: jsPDFInvoiceTemplate.OutputType.Save,
    returnJsPDFDocObject: true,
    fileName:"2021",
    orientationLandscape: false,
    compress: true,
    logo: {
        src: "img/logonew.png",
        type: 'PNG', //optional, when src= data:uri (nodejs case)
        width: 53.33, //aspect ratio = width/height
        height: 26.66,
        margin: {
            top: 0, //negative or positive num, from the current position
            left: 0 //negative or positive num, from the current position
        }
    },
    stamp: {
        inAllPages: true, //by default = false, just in the last page
        src: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edisonneza/jspdf-invoice-template/demo/images/qr_code.jpg",
        type: 'JPG', //optional, when src= data:uri (nodejs case)
        width: 20, //aspect ratio = width/height
        height: 20,
        margin: {
            top: 0, //negative or positive num, from the current position
            left: 0 //negative or positive num, from the current position
        }
    },
    business: {
        name: "Harry",
        address: "Albania, Tirane ish-Dogana, Durres 2001",
        phone: "(+355) 069 11 11 111",
        email: "email@example.com",
        email_1: "info@example.al",
        website: "www.example.al",
    },
    contact: {
        label: "Invoice issued for:",
        name: "Client Name",
        address: "Albania, Tirane, Astir",
        phone: "(+355) 069 22 22 222",
        email: "client@website.al",
        otherInfo: "www.website.al",
    },
    invoice: {
        label: "Invoice #: ",
        num: 19,
        invDate: "Payment Date: 01/01/2021 18:12",
        invGenDate: "Invoice Date: 02/02/2021 10:17",
        headerBorder: false,
        tableBodyBorder: false,
        header: [
          {
            title: "#", 
            style: { 
              width: 10 
            } 
          }, 
          { 
            title: "Title",
            style: {
              width: 30
            } 
          }, 
          { 
            title: "Description",
            style: {
              width: 80
            } 
          }, 
          { title: "Price"},
          { title: "Quantity"},
          { title: "Unit"},
          { title: "Total"}
        ],
        table: Array.from(Array(10), (item, index)=>([
            index + 1,
            "There are many variations ",
            "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text dummy text ",
            200.5,
            4.5,
            "m2",
            400.5
        ])),
        additionalRows: [{
            col1: 'Total:',
            col2: '145,250.50',
            col3: 'ALL',
            style: {
                fontSize: 14 //optional, default 12
            }
        },
        {
            col1: 'VAT:',
            col2: '20',
            col3: '%',
            style: {
                fontSize: 10 //optional, default 12
            }
        },
        {
            col1: 'SubTotal:',
            col2: '116,199.90',
            col3: 'ALL',
            style: {
                fontSize: 10 //optional, default 12
            }
        }],
        invDescLabel: "Invoice Note",
        invDesc: "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary.",
    },
    footer: {
        text: "The invoice is created on a computer and is valid without the signature and stamp.",
    },
    pageEnable: true,
    pageLabel: "Page ",
};
```

Comment: You probably should have edited the above to remove profanities before posting it?!

Comment: perhaps [this codepen example](https://codepen.io/prathees31/pen/JqbOWe) might be of interest. Incidentally I can get the above, with some small changes, to generate a PDF but it appears blank. When viewed with a text editor I can see the data entered

Comment: One approach you could try is to have an already generated PDF template with fillable form fields that you then programmatically fill with the user responses. As an example, the LEADTOOLS JavaScript Document library has the [DocumentFormFields](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/javascript/dox/documentformfields.html) Object for managing and setting form fields in a loaded document. You can find a working demo on this [here](https://demo.leadtools.com/JavaScript/DocumentViewer/?mode=PDFFormFields). (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)